# Meilisearch API key uid not showing up when calling getKey()

Tags: meilisearch

I'm currently using Meilisearch and I need to get the uid of an API key that I am using.  I'm calling their getKey() method with an API key to get information about this key, but I notice that there is no uid field in the response, despite seeing the field in the responses in their docs. Did they change the response to getKey? How can I obtain the uid of an API key?

Answer (score 1):

Meilisearch documentation only reflects the latest version of Meilisearch, which is v0.28. The uid field for keys was introduced in v0.28, so chances are you are using an older Meilisearch version.